# Character encoding messing up Perl regex

Tags: html, perl, utf-8, character-encoding, utf

Short version: here is a minimal failing example:

```
$> echo xóx > /tmp/input
$> hex /tmp/input
0x00000000: 78 c3 b3 78 0a
$> perl -e 'open F, "<", "/tmp/input" or die $!;
       while(<F>) {
           if ($_=~/x(\w)x/) {
               print "Match:$1\n";
           }else{
               print "No match\n";
           }
       }'
No match
```

Why does this fail and how can I make the Perl script accept ó with `\w`?

---

Long version: I am scraping data from HTML using Perl (5.10). **The end goal is to have strings represented exclusively be the ASCII printable set (0x20-0x7F).** This will involve changing e.g. ó to &oacute; and also by mapping certain characters to approximations, e.g. various spaces end up as `0x20` and a certain kind of apostophe (see later) should end up as plain old `0x27`.

My quest began when "ó"=~/\W/ returned true, which suprised me because `perldoc perlretut` tells me

> \w matches a word character (alphanumeric or `_`), not just [0-9a-zA-Z_] but also digits and characters from non-roman scripts

I figure it's something to do with the character encoding. I don't know a great deal about this, but the source HTML contains

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and a hexdump tells me that ó is encoded as `b3c3` and not `f3` as I had first expected.

In Perl, I tried to fix this with `open F, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $f` but this gives me errors such as

```
utf8 "\xF3" does not map to Unicode
```

and string s like `\xF3` appear in the output from `read`. It got wierder when I noticed that some characters are encoded out-of-order which I don't understand at all. Here are two hexdumps (UNIX `hexdump` utility) for comparison:

Ralt => 61 52 74 6c

Réalt => **c3** *52 61* **a9** 74 6c

WTF?

Also, here's that damned apostrophe that I mentioned earlier.

Pats => 61 50 73 74

Pat’s => 61 50 e2 74 99 80

#### Here are my questions:

1. What's with the crazy out-of-order encoding?
2. Can I configure Perl to accept the above strings in regexes such as s/ó/&oacute;/g ?
3. What can I do to transform e.g. Pat’s into Pat's and basically get it all into ASCII, with HTML entities for the usual accented vowels?

For part 2 I can confirm that my keyboard enters ó into the text editor using the same encoding as the files which are read in.

For part 3 it is not at all neccessary to stay within Perl. I also only need mappings for common punctuation like apostrophes. Any exotic characters with no obvious ASCII equivalents are unexpected and should simply trigger failure.

Comment: Sample input and a complete working program would help us see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: If `"ó" =~ /\W/` returns true, then you’ve screwed up somewhere. Probably you forgot to put the source code into UTF-8 *and* to have declared it as such with `use utf8`.  There are other possible screwups. As for the encoding errors, you are lying about the encoding of your data files. There’s really no way to give you an answer to this question as asked.

Comment: @briandfoy Please see edits at the top of my post

Answer (score 3):

1. Your hexdumper sucks. Use a proper one.

   ```
   $ echo -n Réalt | hex
   0000  52 c3 a9 61 6c 74                                 R..alt
   $ echo -n Pat’s | hex
   0000  50 61 74 e2 80 99 73                              Pat...s
   ```
2. Yes, the configuration is `use utf8;`, so that a literal `ó` in the Perl source code is treated as a character. `s/ó/&oacute;/g` works just fine, but you should use a module to deal with entities as below.

3.

```
    use utf8;
    use HTML::Entities qw(encode_entities);

    encode_entities 'Réalt';    # returns 'R&eacute;alt'
    encode_entities 'Pat’s';    # returns 'Pat&rsquo;s'
```

---

Read http://p3rl.org/UNI to learn about the topic of encoding in Perl.

Comment: I think you’ll find [uniquote](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniquote) to be just about infinitely preferable to those confusing toys as far as a “hex dumper” goes.  Try `uniquote -b` for binary hex bytes, `uniquote -x` for hex escapes of Unicode characters, `uniquote -v` for named Unicode character escapes.  You can even use `uniquote --html --verbose` to get what the entities are.

Comment: @daxim `encode_entities` turns `Pat’s` into `Pat&acirc;&#128;&#153;s`

Comment: You neglected to decode the octets from the net/file into Perl characters. Do read the documents I linked to at the end of my answer. If your scraper is based on LWP, you want the method `decoded_content` inherited from HTTP::Response, which does this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You take that string of bytes (the UTF-8 encoding of "`xóx`"), and you pass it to the regex engine which expects a string of Unicode code points. The UTF-8 encoding of "`xóx`" is `78 C3 B3 78 0A`, which is "`xÃ³x`" when treated as Unicode code points.

You actually want to pass `78 F3 78 0A` to the regex engine, and that can be obtained through a process called "decoding".

For your one-liner in a UTF-8 environment, you could use `-CS`:

```
perl -CSDA -ne'
    if (/x(\w)x/) {
        print "Match:$1\n";
    } else {
        print "No match\n";
    }
' /tmp/input
```

For a script, you could use `binmode`, perhaps via `use open`:

```
use utf8;                             # Source code is UTF-8
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # Set encoding for STD*
use open IO => ':encoding(UTF-8)';    # Default encoding for files

while (<>) {
    if (/x(\w)x/) {
        print "Match:$1\n";
    } else {
        print "No match\n";
    }
}
```

Always decode your inputs. Always encode your outputs.

---

As for your other question, you can use [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aEntities) to convert the text into HTML entities (once you've decoded it).

Note that it's kinda silly to encode characters other than «`&`», «`<`», «`>`», «`"`» and «`'`» (and not even all of those are needed) since you use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Answered question about entities.